# Question on Pictometry ImageNavigator API

Tags: pictometry

I am working with Pictometry IMageNavigator API. I have created a simple JavaScript and ASP .NET web application as per instructions given at
http://dev.pictometry.com/imageNavigator/doc/GettingStarted.html.

However in both applications I am getting an error, "this.HitSetRegion.Y is null or not defined". I am looking for some directions to resolve this.

Basically I would be passing Latitude and Longitude values as a URL parameter to this application. But right now I am hard coding the coordinates.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Strongly suggest you confer with Pictometry.  Their customer service is exemplary.